# Redirect with session message when $request->validate() returns with errors

Tags: php, laravel

I'm validating a form by using the `validate()` method at `$request` in the controller. It works, but besides the error messages, available at the `$errors` variable, I would like to put a Session message at an alert component, what we usually do by using the `with()` method when returning a view at the end of the controller method.
However, when the `validate()` method returns me the errors, I didn't find a way to put the session message to it.

The code is this:

```
$request->validate([
  'name' => 'required',
  'cpf' => 'cpf|required',
  'email' => 'email|required',
  'data_de_nascimento' => 'date',
  'data_de_pagamento' => 'date',
  'modalidade' => 'required',
  'instrutor' => 'required',
  'avaliacao' => 'file|required',
);
```

And I would like the `validate()` method return me a Session with these paramenters:

```
'message' => [
  'content' => 'Check the mistaken information!',
  'type' => 'danger',
]
```

Is it possible? Or should I use the Validator class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `$request->validate()` and have a custom error message show it is possible to pass an array of messages to the function like so:

```
$messages = [
    'name.required' => 'Please make sure your name is entered'
];

$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required'
], $messages);
```

and you can display the error message inline in your form like so:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

or you can do what the other answers suggest to have it appear as an alert block

Answer (score 0):

Manually Validate using Validator class is a way.
additionally, you can check like

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">Check the mistaken information!</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your blade file

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```